# How can I deal with areas filled with turrets that are unaccessible to the batmobile?

Tags: batman-arkham-knight

I have found at least 2 areas so far: a checkpoint near the place where you

> fight the Arkham Knight

And the location of one of the crewmembers of firestation 17, near Grand Central Station.

Both areas are filled with turrets, like 5 or 6 turrets at once, combined with several armed or unarmed mooks. I have no idea how to deal with those areas without the batmobile, since the remote hacking device only handles 1 at a time. I have noticed that part of my skill tree is still locked, even though I've finished the storyline already. Is this part needed to deal with these sections? Or is there another way to deal with this checkpoint and this crewmember?

Comment: The checkpoint near the massive lift/drill?

Comment: @Jeeva Yes, that one, where you need to lower the lift by using the power winch on your batmobile.

Comment: @Jeeva I think my comment was not clear enough. I've clarified it further in a comment to your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there's one thing I've found, it's that even when it looks impossible to get the Batmobile to a location, the developers have shoved reliance on it in somewhere.

That said:

> In the case of the drill shaft near the Arkham Knight fight, you will need to lower the lift as far down as it can move. You can then drive the batmobile into the bottom of the lift shaft, and destroy the turret.

You might consider the Disruptor upgrade that causes turrets to explode when they target you, for the second scenario.

Comment: it's not THAT turret at the bottom of the shaft that I mean. I'm talking about the above-ground checkpoint, near that serial killer shrine up on top.

Comment: Righto - will try and remember the one you mean, then.

Comment: I already found the way to handle the firefighter rescue mission: you can open a way for the batmobile to get up there from the other side.

Answer (score 1):

The disruptor upgrade does indeed work, and is how I ended up beating these two (IIRC) checkpoints. They turn both into pretty fast work; disrupt both, and while you're dealing with the typically two or three out of range of the turrets, the turrets take care of the rest of them.

Comment: Even without the upgrade, it's probably possible, albeit harder and tedious - time the turret sweeps while taking down separated guards one at a time, grapnelling out and healing if necessary. It's been a while, however, and I don't even remember if it's possible to take down a (large) turret the hard way.